# How to show dominators view in chrome developer tools?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, profiling, google-chrome-devtools

I need it to track down what is holding on to some objects that I think should be garbage collected. I am trying to open the dominators view in chrome developer tools, but it does not seem to be there:

[image: Screen shot of heap view selection]

I have selected "record advanced heap shots" in the developer settings.

Any idea how to show the dominators view?

Comment: According to https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/profile/memory-problems/heap-snapshots you need to open up the Dev Tools settings and enabling "Show advanced heap snapshot properties" and restarting the Dev Tools. 

I tried it though and it didn't seem to work.

Comment: I tried that too. And it didn't work for me either.

Answer (score 0):

I've been searching for this setting, too. But it doesn't exist any more, according to [this bug report comment](https://issues.chromium.org/issues/41231894#comment3):

> Status: Won't Fix (Obsolete) - Jan 11, 2016
>
> Dominators and Containment views have been intentionally removed a while ago.